# How can I display an image in my query using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to display an airline image underneath an airline name. I have stored paths in my XML file for the airlineImage. How would I go about displaying the image in my query using LINQ?

Here's my code so far:

```
var query = from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata2.xml")).Elements("flight")
                    select new
                    {                        
                        Airline = (string)f.Element("airline"),
                        DepartureAirportSymbol = (string)f.Element("departureAirportSymbol"),
                        DepartTime = (string)f.Element("departureTime"),
                        DestinationAirportSymbol = (string)f.Element("destinationAirportSymbol"),
                        ArrivalTime = (string)f.Element("arrivalTime"),
                        Stops = (int)f.Element("numberOfStops"),
                        Duration = (string)f.Element("duration"),
                        Cabin = (string)f.Element("class"),
                        Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price")
                    };

    this.GridView1.DataSource = query;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: It really sounds like you shouldn't be doing it this way, perhaps process your xml into a simple dictionary when your web application first loads the xml file.

Comment: Well, the picture column in your grid should host some picture control, which is given a path to an image file would load the actual image.

I do not think, Linq has anything to do with it. All it does is queries information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select new
{
   Duration = (string)f.Element("duration"),
   Cabin = (string)f.Element("class"),
   Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price")
   ImagePath = (string)f.Element("airlineImage")
};


<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
      <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImagePath" 
                      DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Content/Images/{0}" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

UPDATE 
1. You have to replace path `~/Content/Images/{0}` in GridView to where you store your images.
2. Set AutoGenerateColumns="false" so your grid will only contains colums that you have defined.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the images don't seem to display. There is a box that says "Image" where the image should appear. Also there is the column of ImagePath that I don't want to display.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. You should check carefully where you store your images. Alternatively check source HTML of your page to see if <img src leads to the right place.

Comment: Great. I got the images to display. I want to get rid of the         ImagePath column from my gridview. Is there a way to hide the last column in the linq query? I tried GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false and it says that the index was out of range.

Comment: The best way will be settting AutoGenerateColumns="false" and define all columns that you want in <Columns> tag manually. Otherwise GridView automatically creates columns and I don't know how to access them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be best served by loading the path into your object then setting the src attribute of the image dynamically:

```
<img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' />
```